# Rendering extremely large number of images with a python script

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I am using Blender to create an image dataset with multiple objects placed differently. The scene is mostly static with a few elements changing positions. The time to render each image is around 2.8s after optimizing render settings.

My current approach is to read in the position information for the objects from a json file, move the objects to the necessary positions and render out an image. Something like

```
import bpy

class Renderer:
...
...
    def apply_moves(self):
         for i,moves in self._read_moves().items():
             for name, translation in moves.items():
                 bpy.data.objects[name].location = Vector(translation)
             self.render_scene(f'scene{int(i):07d}.jpg')
         bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
 
    def render_scene(self,filename):
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(self._settings['OUTPUT_DIR'],filename)
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

However, I plan on rendering **500,000** such images and at 2.8s per image that is around **16.2 days**. The rendering uses only around 1GB of memory. I have access to a 48GB GPU and 128GB of RAM. Is there a way to render multiple such scenes concurrently to save total time?

I didn't find any relevant information online, could you point me in the right direction?

## UPDATE

My current approach has been to run several instances of blender simultaneously.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh                                                                                                                                        
blender a.blend -b -P render.py -- 10000 20000 > /dev/null &                                                                                         
blender a.blend -b -P render.py -- 160000 190000 > /dev/null &                                                                                       
blender a.blend -b -P render.py -- 190000 220000 > /dev/null &                                                                                       
blender a.blend -b -P render.py -- 220000 250000 > /dev/null &                                                                                       
blender a.blend -b -P render.py -- 250000 280000 > /dev/null &
```

This however does not scale very well. For example with 5 such instances I am rendering out an image every second at best and sometimes it is as low as 1 every 3.2s (average around 1.6s per image).

Can this be improved?

Comment: you can run multiple instances using the blender command line arguments https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is what I have been doing currently, however the performance doesn't scale linearly. With 4 instances the time taken is only reduced by a factor of 2.

Comment: use multiprocessing inside each subprocess/instance.

Comment: Could you elaborate?